# Spring boot customize Jackson serialization to return the object instead appending the type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

When return list of submission objects it returns the object list as submissionList.

```
        final Page<Submission> pa= new PageImpl<>(Arrays.asList(new Submission()));

    pa.getContent().stream().forEach(obj -> linkBuilder.buildLink(obj));
    final HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    final PagedResourcesAssembler<Submission> assembler = new PagedResourcesAssembler<>(resolver, null);
    PagedResources<Resource<Submission>> resources = assembler.toResource(pa);
    return new ResponseEntity(resources, HttpStatus.OK);
```

In a Rest Get endpoint if we return as below it gives the response as below

```
"_embedded": {
    "submissionList": [
        {  "field1":1
        },
        {  "field1":1
        }
    ]
```

}

expected Response

```
"_embedded": {
    "submission": [
        {  "field1":1
        },
        {  "field1":1
        }
    ]
```

}

How can we override jackson to have the above response

Comment: You can use @JsonProperty("submission") on submissionList class variable.

Comment: @Akash We dont have a SubmissionList class variable as Its using Spring pagination provided Page object to set the submission list